# Using SQL CASE/WHEN output for calculation

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I've got the following query that I'd like to use in order to convert an amount from various currencies into USD:

```
SELECT 
    currency, 
    CASE currency 
      WHEN 'SAR' THEN 0.266
      WHEN 'EGP' THEN 0.113
      WHEN 'USD' THEN 1
      WHEN 'JOD' THEN 1.411
      WHEN 'GBP' THEN 1.311
      WHEN 'BHD' THEN 2.652
      WHEN 'AED' THEN 0.272
      WHEN 'EUR' THEN 1.111
      WHEN 'QAR' THEN 0.275
      WHEN 'KWD' THEN 3.315
      ELSE 0 
    END as in_usd,
    SUM(amount)*in_usd as total_in_usd
FROM 
    mytable
WHERE 
    created_at >= current_date - '7 days'::INTERVAL 
GROUP BY 
    currency
```

This fails with the message `in_usd does not exist`.

The expected output is a list of currencies and their totals:

```
currency total_in_usd
USD      100.00
AED      59.00
GBP      143.01
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have the right structure - one minor tweak should make it work just fine. Multiply the currency conversion when doing the sum -

```
SELECT 
    currency, 
    SUM(amount)*
      (CASE currency 
          WHEN 'SAR' THEN 0.266
          WHEN 'EGP' THEN 0.113
          WHEN 'USD' THEN 1
          WHEN 'JOD' THEN 1.411
          WHEN 'GBP' THEN 1.311
          WHEN 'BHD' THEN 2.652
          WHEN 'AED' THEN 0.272
          WHEN 'EUR' THEN 1.111
          WHEN 'QAR' THEN 0.275
          WHEN 'KWD' THEN 3.315
          ELSE 0 
      END) as total_in_usd
FROM 
    mytable
WHERE 
    created_at >= current_date - '7 days'::INTERVAL 
GROUP BY 
    currency
```

Comment: This works great .. and no sub-queries! Thanks a ton

Answer (score 4):

Put the `CASE` expression part in a derived table. Do `GROUP BY` on it's result:

```
select currency, in_usd, SUM(amount) * in_usd as total_in_usd
from
(
SELECT 
    currency, 
    CASE currency 
      WHEN 'USD' THEN 1
      WHEN 'SAR' THEN 0.266
      WHEN 'EGP' THEN 0.113
      WHEN 'USD' THEN 1
      WHEN 'JOD' THEN 1.411
      WHEN 'GBP' THEN 1.311
      WHEN 'BHD' THEN 2.652
      WHEN 'AED' THEN 0.272
      WHEN 'EUR' THEN 1.111
      WHEN 'QAR' THEN 0.275
      WHEN 'KWD' THEN 3.315
      ELSE 0 
    END as in_usd,
    amount
FROM 
    mytable
WHERE 
    created_at >= current_date - '7 days'::INTERVAL 
)
GROUP BY 
    currency, in_usd
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SELECT_list.html):

The alias is not recognized until the entire target list has been parsed, which means that you cannot refer to the alias elsewhere within the target list. For example, the following statement will fail:

```
select (qtysold + 1) as q, sum(q) from sales group by 1;
ERROR:  column "q" does not exist
```

You can fix this with a subselect:

```
SELECT inner.currency, inner.in_usd, inner.sum_amount*inner.in_usd as total_in_usd
from (
    SELECT 
        currency, 
        CASE currency 
          WHEN 'SAR' THEN 0.266
          WHEN 'EGP' THEN 0.113
          WHEN 'USD' THEN 1
          WHEN 'JOD' THEN 1.411
          WHEN 'GBP' THEN 1.311
          WHEN 'BHD' THEN 2.652
          WHEN 'AED' THEN 0.272
          WHEN 'EUR' THEN 1.111
          WHEN 'QAR' THEN 0.275
          WHEN 'KWD' THEN 3.315
          ELSE 0 
        END as in_usd,
        SUM(amount) as sum_amount
    FROM 
    mytable
WHERE 
    created_at >= current_date - '7 days'::INTERVAL 
GROUP BY 
    currency) inner
```

Comment: Excellent, and thanks for the link to the documentation! On a separate note, is it possible to create a function out of the case/when so that I can reference it from multiple queries?

Comment: I've never created a stored function on amazon redshitf. But, according to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_FUNCTION.html), it's possible both in SQL and python.